# How can we make the Google App script able to send POST request on a webhook which is only accessible within my Internal Network

Tags: google-apps-script, bots, google-workspace, google-developers-console

I have created a Google-app Script which will take the slash commands(/job;/help etc) from the GoogleChat App and sends the POST request to respective webhook api which is only accessible within Internal network,
How can I able to successfully send POST request without exposing my webhook api publicly,

Thanks

Comment: You can't.  The script is running on a computer far beyond your network.  There is no path.